# MS Access - Log daily totals of query in new table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an ODBC database that I've linked to an Access table. I've been using Access to generate some custom queries/reports.

However, this ODBC database changes frequently and I'm trying to discover where the discrepancy is coming from. (hundreds of thousands of records to go through, but I can easily filter it down into what I'm concerned about)

Right now I've been manually pulling the data each day, exporting to Excel, counting the totals for each category I want to track, and logging in another Excel file.

I'd rather automate this in Access if possible, but haven't been able to get my heard around it yet.

I've already linked the ODBC databases I'm concerned with, and can generate the query I want to generate.

What I'm struggling with is how to capture this daily and then log that total so I can trend it over a given time period.

If it the data was constant, this would be easy for me to understand/do. However, the data can change daily.

EX: This is a database of work orders. Work orders(which are basically my primary key) are assigned to different departments. A single work order can belong to many different departments and have multiple tasks/holds/actions tied to it.

Work Order 0237153-03 could be assigned to Department A today, but then could be reassigned to Department B tomorrow.

These work orders also have "ranking codes" such as Priority A, B, C. These too can be changed at any given time. Today Work Order 0237153-03 could be priority A, but tomorrow someone may decide that it should actually be Priority B.

This is why I want to capture all  available data each day (The new work orders that have come in overnight, and all the old work orders that may have had changes made to them), count the totals of the different fields I'm concerned about, then log this data.

Then repeat this everyday.

Comment: Try editing your question and providing sample data and desired results.  As written, it is really too vague to answer.

Comment: You say you have a 'database' - is this an existing Access database, or an Excel 'database', SQL Server, Oracle?  There is a way to link it in, but need to know what it is first - and then it's a simple task to count how many are active on any given day - providing the data has a date and something that says it's active.

Comment: There is definitely a way.  Create a query that contains the logic you are doing manually and have it append the log data to a table.  For more specific answer, as others have said, we need more to go on.

Comment: Added more information. I would provide screen shots and what not, but all this is on another PC that doesn't have internet access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the question you ask is very vague so here is a general answer.

You are counting the items you get from a database table.

It may be that you don't need to actually count them every day, but if the table in the database stores all the data for every day, you simply need to create a query to count the items that are in the table for every day that is stored in the table.

You are right that this would be best done in access.

You might not have the "log the counts in another table" though.

It seems you are quite new to access so you might benefit form these links videos numbered 61, 70  [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLYMOUCVo86jEeMMdaaq03jQ_t9nFV737s)  and also video 7 [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLYMOUCVo86jEgD_6ZgePmPOwGixSPr5FZ)

These will help or buy a book / use web resources.

PART2.

If you have to bodge it because you can't get the ODBC database to use triggers/data macros to log a history you could store a history yourself like this.... BUT you have to do it EVERY day.

0 On day 1 take a full copy of the ODBC data as YOURTABLE.  Add a field "dump Number" and set it all to 1.
1. Link to the ODBC data every day.

2. join from YOURTABLE to the ODBC table and find any records that have changed (ie test just the fields you want to monitor and if any of them have changed...).
3. Append these changed records to YOURTABLE with a new value for "dump number of 2" This MUST always increment!
4. You can now write SQL to get the most recent record for each primary key.

   ```
    SELECT *  
     FROM Mytable
     WHERE 
     (
     SELECT PrimaryKeyFields, MAX(DumpNumber) AS MAXDumpNumber
     FROM Mytable
     GROUP BY  PrimaryKeyFields
     ) AS T1
     ON t1.PrimaryKeyFields = Mytable.PrimaryKeyFields 
        AND t1.MAXDumpNumber= Mytable.DumpNumber
   ```
5. You can compare the most recent records with any previous records.
   ie to get the previous dump
   Note that this will NOT work in the abvoe SQL (unless you always keep every record!)

   ```
   AND t1.MAXDumpNumber-1 = Mytable.DumpNumber
   ```

   Use something like this to get the previous row:

   ```
    SELECT *  
     FROM Mytable
          INNER JOIN 
             (
             SELECT PrimaryKeyFields
                  , MAX(DumpNumber) AS MAXDumpNumber
             FROM Mytable
                  INNER JOIN 
                 (
                 SELECT PrimaryKeyFields
                      , MAX(DumpNumber) AS MAXDumpNumber
                 FROM Mytable
                 GROUP BY  PrimaryKeyFields
                 ) AS TabLatest 
                 ON TabLatest.PrimaryKeyFields = Mytable.PrimaryKeyFields 
                    AND 
                    TabLatest.MAXDumpNumber <> Mytable.DumpNumber   
                    -- Note that the  <> is VERY important
             GROUP BY  PrimaryKeyFields
             ) AS T1
             ON t1.PrimaryKeyFields = Mytable.PrimaryKeyFields 
                AND t1.MAXDumpNumber= Mytable.DumpNumber
   ```
6. Create 4 and 5 and MS Access named queries (or SS views) and then treate them like tables to do comparison.

Make sure you have indexes created on the PK fields and the DumpNumber and they shoudl be unique - this will speed things up....

7. Finish it in time for christmas... and flag this as an answer!

Comment: I've added a better description in my original question. I'm tracking work orders which have fields that can change at any given time. THis is why I want to take a daily snapshot of how many work orders a particular group was assigned. This allows me to analyze how work is flowing through my organization. Using only the data available on a given day doesn't give me a clear enough picture.

Comment: Doing this in access "daily" would be a bodge.  What you ideally need is for the system you are connecting to to keep a history of the records (or fields) that you need to access the history for.  See part two of my answer.